# Refactor catch statements

Tags: flutter, exception, try-catch

We have many try-catch blocks in our code handling the exceptions of the api calls. Since most of the catch blocks are identical we want to refactor them and only them (because the try blocks should stay in the place they are). How is this possible in Flutter?

Example code:

```
try {
  _userData = apiService.call("user_data");
} on ResourceNotFoundException {
  handleResourceNotFoundException();
} on NetworkException {
  handleNetworkException();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I found is using a general `catch`, fit everything into a `handleException` function, and in there rethrow the exception again.

```
try {
  _userData = apiService.call("user_data");
} on catch (e) {
  handleException(e);
}


void handleException(e) {
   try {
      throw e;
   } on ResourceNotFoundException {
      handleResourceNotFoundException();
   } on NetworkException {
      handleNetworkException();
   }
 }
```

This way it is possible to reuse the exception handling logic and also extend it.

Comment: Clever method. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

In case of repetitive try catch blocks, using a generic function to handle errors in one place would be also a convenient solution.

```
  Future<T> _fetchDataAndHandleErrors<T>(Future<T> Function() callback) async {
    try {
      return await callback();
    } on ResourceNotFoundException {
      handleResourceNotFoundException();
    } on NetworkException {
      handleNetworkException();
    }
    ...
  }
```

In your case, you would invoke `_fetchDataAndHandleErrors` function like this:

```
  Future<UserData> getUserData() async {
    return await _fetchDataAndHandleErrors(
      () async {
        userData = apiService.call("user_data");
        return userData;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some abstraction to your API call, meaning you should add a function that takes in the API call you are trying to call as a parameter and surround it with a try-catch block and handle all your exceptions there.

This way you have separated your API calls logic from handling exceptions.

Comment: If you look closely, you see this exact abstraction already. In our `apiService` we have an abstracted version of a dio client that catches all exceptions and rethrows our own exception types. Now we propagate our own exceptions into our viewmodels, where we want to handle them properly. This is where this question is placed and it remains open.

Comment: Ok, now I guess I understand what are you trying to achieve.
You what to get rid of the catch blocks all over your code, am I right?

Comment: Well let's say I want to reuse the common catch blocks on multiple occasions.

Comment: You can try making a base class exception and let all other derived exceptions inhert from. This way you will only catch the base exception without the need to catch every type of exception wt every API.

Comment: We already have this in place. But the problem is about the handling of each concrete exception type with its own default handler.

Comment: You can make something like BaseRespone that has both data and error fields, so whenever the response is ok, pass the data but when an exception is thrown catch it and handle it then return as an error in the Baseresonse.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you're getting my question. I simply wanna reuse the catch block. Not less, not more.